# I want to do some operation on $stateChangeSuccess. But It should not be done if I click on browser back button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to do some functionality on `$stateChangeSuccess`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {   
                $rootScope.guestNav.push(toState);
        });
```

And the above code should not work when I click browser back button that is on `popstate` event. Please help me to solve this issue. Or provide me a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use new life cycle events? E.g.

```
.run(($transitions, $state, $injector) => {
  'ngInject';

  $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'app.home' },
    () => console.log('accessing to app home state'));
});
```